# scrapy: switch out failing proxies

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I'm using [this script](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies/blob/master/randomproxy.py) to randomize proxies in scrapy. The problem is that once it's allocated a proxy to a request, it won't allocate another one because of this code:

```
 def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Don't overwrite with a random one (server-side state for IP)
        if 'proxy' in request.meta:
            return
```

That means that if there is a bad proxy which is not connecting to anything, then the request will fail. I'm intending to modify it like this:

```
if request.meta.get('retry_times',0) < 5:
     return
```

thereby letting it allocate a new proxy if the current one fails 5 times. I'm assuming that if I set `RETRY_TIMES` to, say 20, in `settings.py`, then the request won't fail until 4 different proxies have each made 5 attempts.

I'd like to know if that will cause any problems. As I understand it, the reason that the check is there in the first place is for stateful transactions, such as those relying on log-ins, or perhaps cookies. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

I bumped with the same problem.
I [improved](https://github.com/danmash/scrapy-proxies) the [aivarsk/scrapy-proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies/blob/master/randomproxy.py). My middleware inherited by basic RetryMiddleware and trying to use one proxy RETRY_TIMES. If proxy is unavailable, the middleware change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think the idea of that script was to check if the user is already defining a proxy on the meta parameter, so it can control it from the spider.

Setting it to change proxy every 5 times is ok, but I think you'll have to re login to the page, as most pages know when you changed from where you are making the request (proxy).

The idea if rotating proxies is not as easy as just selecting one randomly, because you could still end up using the same proxy, and also defining the rules for when a site "banned" you is not as simple as only checking statuses. This are the services I know for that thing you want: [Crawlera](http://crawlera.com/) and [Proxymesh](http://proxymesh.com/).

If you want direct functionality on scrapy for rotating proxies, I recommend to use `Crawlera` as it is already fully integrated.

Comment: The pages I'm crawling don't require a login. I go to one page, that has a list of links to other pages. Those other pages are the ones that I want. The requests sometimes get routed via a 302, but other than that is straightforward. I realise that a proxy might get chosen twice in a row. But If I set it up so that it tries 4 times, I can live with the possibility that the same proxy gets chosen 4 times in a row.

Comment: check that also don't need to change proxy when doing a redirect, because redirects are in fact two requests, and most times the redirect request won't get you banned.